# can't write unknown attribute `info' PrawnPDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I'm using Prawn PDF to generate an invoice PDF on the fly and I keep getting the error "can't write unknown attribute 'info'" but I don't have an attribute 'info' anywhere in any of the concerned database tables (or my entire database for that matter). I don't know if it's something in the gem that I'm missing. Here is the tutorial I'm following: http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/  and http://www.sitepoint.com/pdf-generation-rails/

I did register the mime type in the initializer (didn't show bc it's so simple, but I can if that's needed)

I also restarted the server multiple times to make sure that wasn't the issue.

I know the gem is installed properly because I can generate an empty PDF no problem, but when I try to add in @invoice is when I run into the issue.

Invoice Show Controller Action:

```
def show
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    @customer = @invoice.customer
    @user = current_user
    @company = @user.company

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            pdf = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "invoice_#{@invoice.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
        end
    end
end
```

InvoicePdf.rb

```
class InvoicePdf < Prawn::Document

    def intialize(invoice)
        super()
        @invoice = invoice
    end

    def header
        image "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", width: 530, height: 150
    end

    def text_content
        y_position = cursor - 50

        bounding_box([0, y_position], :width => 270, :height => 300) do
          text "Lorem ipsum", size: 15, style: :bold
          text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Suspendisse interdum semper placerat. Aenean mattis fringilla risus ut fermentum. Fusce posuere dictum venenatis. Aliquam id tincidunt ante, eu pretium eros. Sed eget risus a nisl aliquet scelerisque sit amet id nisi. Praesent porta molestie ipsum, ac commodo erat hendrerit nec. Nullam interdum ipsum a quam euismod, at consequat libero bibendum. Nam at nulla fermentum, congue lectus ut, pulvinar nisl. Curabitur consectetur quis libero id laoreet. Fusce dictum metus et orci pretium, vel imperdiet est viverra. Morbi vitae libero in tortor mattis commodo. Ut sodales libero erat, at gravida enim rhoncus ut."
        end

        bounding_box([300, y_position], :width => 270, :height => 300) do
          text "Duis vel", size: 15, style: :bold
          text "Duis vel tortor elementum, ultrices tortor vel, accumsan dui. Nullam in dolor rutrum, gravida turpis eu, vestibulum lectus. Pellentesque aliquet dignissim justo ut fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut venenatis massa non eros venenatis aliquet. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris sed tincidunt mauris, et vulputate risus. Aliquam eget nibh at erat dignissim aliquam non et risus. Fusce mattis neque id diam pulvinar, fermentum luctus enim porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos."
        end
    end

end
```

Full Trace:

```
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:72:in `write_attribute'
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:68:in `write_attribute'
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:390:in `[]='
    pdf-core (0.6.0) lib/pdf/core/document_state.rb:42:in `normalize_metadata'
    pdf-core (0.6.0) lib/pdf/core/document_state.rb:5:in `initialize'
    prawn (2.0.2) lib/prawn/document.rb:200:in `new'
    prawn (2.0.2) lib/prawn/document.rb:200:in `initialize'
    app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:23:in `new'
    app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in show'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:258:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:258:in `respond_to'
    app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:20:in `show'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
    better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
    railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
    railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
    /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: That looks like a ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError which comes from Rails (not Prawn). Can you post more of the error message?

Comment: @Unixmonkey I added the full trace does that help? 

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in InvoicesController#show

Comment: I know it could sounds stupid, but are you sure you've run ```rake db:migrate``` before ?

Comment: @OlivierBuffon yup I did.

Answer (score 0):

Still have no idea what the problem was, but it must've had a glitch on the install. I redid the whole setup for prawn and it works now...nothing else different.