# Rails 4 with prawn: can't write unknown attribute `info`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I have this exact same problem: [can't write unknown attribute `info' PrawnPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966557/cant-write-unknown-attribute-info-prawnpdf)

However, the question has no answer, just that he reinstalled prawn. 
I did a gem uninstall prawn, then a bundle install to reinstall the gem, but I still get the error.

The only thing that changed is that when running rails s, now I get these warnings:

C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime:PDF
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here

Could it be I uninstalled and reinstalled incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Does the  "can't write unknown attribute `info' message" has a file and linenr? how do the file look like? does the error also  occur when you create a minimal PDF?

Comment: could you provide a demo project somewhere with the basic implementation where you get the error message?

Answer (score 2):

The error of the mimetype is because you probably have

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

in your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` which is already registered. Please remove that line

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error, and I tried both Manuel and Aulait's fixes but neither worked for me. After I reverted to some previous changes, I noticed that super requires parentheses, regardless if you are passing anything in.

```
def initialize(x, view)
  super()
  @x = x
end
```

That's all I ended up needing to do to fix the problem! Good luck : )

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but it caused this error when sending a parameter to the initialize when my InvoicePdf inherited from Prawn::Document.

I worked around it by removing the inheritance, and using an instance variable, with a get method, not the best but it works.

Final code:

```
class InvoicePdf 
  def initialize(invoice, view)
    @doc = Prawn::Document.new
  end

  def getDoc
    return @doc
  end
end
```